# How do you pronounce System V and SysV?

Tags: system-v

Is the V in System V and SysV (and sysvinit, etc) pronounced "vee" or "five"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it is a roman numeral, "five" is probably the more correct pronounciation...

Wikipedia [agrees as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V):

> Unix System V, commonly abbreviated SysV (and usually pronounced—though rarely written—as "System Five"), ...