# Pronunciation for /usr directory

Tags: directory

How do you pronunce `/usr`?

I found in the net that someone reads it "user"... but, for what I know, this directory is not related to the user. The meaning of the acronym is "Unix specific (or system) resources".

How can we better read it, making it easy to immediately understand the sense of the scope of such folder?

Comment: @RubanSavvy This has been [discussed on the meta site before](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73/are-history-questions-on-topic/), and the moderators seem to agree that questions related to Unix history are on-topic.

Comment: @illuminÉ I think this question can fall under "Using or administering a *nix desktop or server". To use or administer something, you need to be able to talk about it. Questions about *nix terminology are on topic IMO. There are actually [quite](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6197/22222) [a few](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2212/22222) [of them](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8677/22222) already but, as you can see by the votes on this and similar questions, the community considers them on topic. In cases where the help docs and the community disagree, the community always wins.

Comment: Thomas Nyman & terdon. I understand you both. The history of the /usr directory is certainly part of the history of Unix, and I can see the value in having knowledge about the use of an acronym in re "admin". Just hard to conceive that someone with even basic command of the English language wonders about the pronunciation of "usr" (just to be clear I'm no native speaker). That's why I think the answers to thisQ are about history and basically contain a line about pronunciation which comes as an afterthought. But I dig the inclusive spirit and respect the community's decision.

Comment: /usr/bin/bad - Only one way to read it in my mind!

Comment: "The meaning of the acronym is Unix specific (or system) resources." Any research shows that 'USR' as an acronym for the user directory is 'retroactive'.

Comment: The correct pronunciation is YOOZER. :)

Comment: pehr-uh-esh-e-err :-)

Comment: Some years ago, at a previous job, I worked on Unix systems with the usual `/usr` et al setup, and with users' home directories under `/user`. In that context, pronouncing `/usr` as "slash user" would not have been a good idea. But I've never seen `/user` used that way before or since, so it was probably an unusual case.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In the original Unix implementations, [`/usr` used to contain the user home directories](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html), e.g. instead of `/home/user`, you would have `/usr/user`. The original intention was for the directory to be called ´user´ with the connotation "everything user related".

Since then, the role of `/usr` has narrowed. In current Unix-like operating systems, `/usr` still tends to contain user-land programs and data (as opposed to 'system' programs and data), although in many cases the [distinction between for instance `/usr/bin` and `/bin`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/difference-between-bin-and-usr-bin) isn't perhaps as strong as it used to be.

Perhaps the pronunciation 'user' is more understandable given this background. A [backronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym) some people prefer is 'User System Resources', but 'user' is still more common.

Comment: [It does look like that passage has been removed from the FHS, however.](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEUSRHIERARCHY)

Comment: FWIW, I use many modern HPC systems where the home directories are still in a directory under `/usr` for some reason.

Comment: @Thomas, Since there's already usr, why did `home` get invented?

Comment: @Pacerier, Reasons for the addition of `/home` are covered by [jilliagre's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121274/43779) to [this related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121258/43779).

Answer (score 31):

The "Unix specific (or system) resources" is a backronym. As already stated, it is just a shorten form of user. See this related [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8677/why-do-usr-and-tmp-directories-for-linux-miss-vowels-in-their-spellings)

I tend to pronounce it "user" with experienced people, i.e. those knowing what I'm talking about, and "u-ess-err" with the ones I'm unsure.

Comment: So now I know that if you "u-ess-err" me you are being condescending :)

Comment: If I **know** you, that might be the case indeed ;-) otherwise, I just don't take the risk being misunderstood.

Answer (score 17):

I can personally vouch that it's been pronounced "user" since at least the early eighties, when portability across OS's (and with it the concept of "unix-specific" as opposed to system-independent resources) was not on anyone's map. "Unix-specific resources" is definitely a later invention, or "folk etymology".

As @Thomas demonstrates, it used to contain more obviously "user" stuff. In older systems, `/usr` was often a disk mount point, so that system essentials were on the root drive or partition (`/`), and `/usr` would contain userland programs and data that can be loaded later in the boot process.

Answer (score 13):

Some time ago, I found the [Low Fat Linux tutorial](http://lowfatlinux.com), which has [this brief explanation](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-directories.html) about the Linux file sistem.

In short, it lists the following definitions:

> - **/bin** Contains the Linux system commands and programs (also called binaries). Pronounced "slash bin."
> - **/dev** Contains special device files that correspond to hardware components. Pronounced "slash dev."
> - **/etc** Contains configuration files for Linux and other installed software. Pronounced "slash et-see."
> - **/home** Contains the home directories (personal storage) for each user on the system. Pronounced "slash home."
> - **/sbin** Contains more Linux binaries (special utilities not for general users). Pronounced "slash ess-bin."
> - **/root** The home directory for the root user; not to be confused with /. Some Linux systems use /home/root instead of /root. Pronounced "slash root."
> - **/usr** Contains system programs and other files for general users such as games, online help, and documentation. By convention, a user should not put personal files in this directory. Pronounced "slash user."

Comment: I went through a video training course where the instructor kept saying "slash-etcetera".  Fortunately I already knew the correct pronunciation, so it was just annoying (and surprising) instead of setting me up to be laughed at.

Comment: @Wildcard I don't think I've never heard of `/etc` being pronounced _et-see_ except by Americans. Maybe this is regional variance (like the pronunciation of _router_), but here in the UK I know it as _etcetera_ or possibly _ee-tee-see_.

Comment: Let's be honest: as long as the message is clear, pronunciation may be irrelevant

Answer (score 11):

Might as well go to the source. In this 1982 film from AT&T that features the UNIX inventors, [The UNIX Operating System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tc4ROCJYbm0), Brian Kernighan pronounces `/usr` as "user", around the 13:41 mark. He is showing his home directory, `/usr/bwk`.

Until computers running UNIX got large user bases and multiple disk drives, almost all users' home directories were directly under `/usr`.