# At what point did the /home directory appear?

Tags: directory-structure, history, home, fhs

Originally in Unix, `/usr` was used for user (home) directories. So if I had a user named `alex`, my home directory would be `/usr/alex`. (Interestingly, [Plan 9](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/), the successor to Unix, still has user directories in `/usr`.)

Nowadays, of course, we store home directories in `/home`. (At least on GNU/Linux. I don't know about other Unices, but OS X doesn't count.) At what point did this become standard practice? What Unix flavor did it appear in? How long did adoption by other Unices take? Has `/home` been adopted by everyone?

I've done some searching on here, but turned up nothing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This change was introduced by BSD after 1985 (BSD 4.2 was still [documenting](http://modman.unixdev.net/?sektion=7&page=hier&manpath=4.2BSD) `/usr`) and in or before 1988 (BSD 4.3/SunOS 4.1 `hier(7)` manual page already [documents](http://modman.unixdev.net/?manpath=SunOS-4.1.3&page=hier&sektion=7&apropos=) `/home`). It was quickly followed by Solaris 2.0 (which kind of merged System V and BSD) and was later adopted by most other Unix vendors.

This is from the Solaris 2.0 `useradd` manual page:

```
   -D          Display the default values for group, basedir, skel, shell,
               inactive, and expire.  When used with the -g, -b, -f, or -e
               options,  the  -D  option  sets  the default values for the
               specified fields.  The default values are:

                       group       other (GID of 1)
                       basedir     /home
                       skel        /etc/skel
                       shell       /sbin/sh
                       inactive    0
                       expire      Null (unset).
```

Before that, older Unixes were using either the traditional `/usr` directory or some variants like /user1 documented in SVR3 and SVR4.0. Unix version 7 `hier(7)` [manual page](http://modman.unixdev.net/?sektion=7&page=hier&manpath=v7man) defines `/usr` as the default location for user's home directory:

```
/usr/wd/     initial working directory of a user, typically wd is the
             user's login name
```

Unix version 6, the first Unix to be widely released outside of the Bell Labs had not the `hier` manual page yet but was already using and [documenting](http://wwwlehre.dhbw-stuttgart.de/~helbig/os/v6/doc/beg.ps) `/usr`.

There are several reasons that explain the move from `/usr` to something else, including:

- With some Unix versions, upgrading the OS was [blowing away the `/usr` directory](http://openindiana.org/pipermail/oi-dev/2012-September/001726.html).
- Usernames like `tmp`, `src`, `bin`, `local` and the likes were forbidden as they clashed with existing directories under `/usr`.
- Using `/usr` as an automounter base directory was not possible as it was not empty (Thanks to Johan for pointing this)
- Diskless machines were expected to use a read only NFS share for `/usr` but read-write home directories

Comment: Another reason (for using /home) was to separate it out from /usr in order to be able to Automount the user home dirs.

Comment: A related question - how did FreeBSD come to adopt `/usr/home` instead?

Comment: My best guess would be FreeBSD didn't want to be too much disruptive.

Comment: AIX 3.1 used /u for user home directories. When AIX 3.2 came out around 1991 the home directory was switched to /home.